Create a recycle bin in Ubuntu (openmediavault)
I want to create a folder (/recycle), in which only deleted files from the folder (/folder1) will remain. Is it possible to first create a backup of the folder (/folder1) with rsync, and then delete the duplicates in (/recycle)?
I want to somehow create an analogue of the recycle bin in openmediavault, but which will work with all folders and protocols. (By default, the recycle bin is available only in the user folder and via the SMB protocol)
